# Localization doesn't work

Tags: django, localization

I created a Django site with localization built in, using `python manage.py runserver` to test it. But after setting it live with Apache/WSGI, the localization doesn't work correctly.

I can see dates being translated (so somehow it knows the current language), but all my site-specific strings are untranslated.

I have no idea where to look though on where to fix this.

When running on the Django console, it works fine:

```
>>> import django.utils.translation
>>> django.utils.translation.activate('nl')
>>> django.utils.translation.ugettext('Articles')
u'Artikelen'
```

But when using the same code in a view:

```
from django.utils import translation

def page_test(request):
    translation.activate('nl')
    return HttpResponse(translation.ugettext("Articles"))
```

this returns `Articles`.

Comment: I wouldn't know why this doesn't work. Did you try a string from the default translations eg.: 'Duration'?

Comment: @SandervanLeeuwen that does work. I can see 'Search' being translated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my `LOCALE_PATHS` was incorrect. I had this code in my `settings.py`:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__)) 
LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'locale'), )
```

but in the live situation, `SITE_ROOT` was empty. I replaced it with

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )
```

and it works now.